# why homepage is not showing while runserver in django and after uploading in heroku it's not working?

Tags: python, html, django

starting new in django, first i run pipenv and pipenv shell in cmd and then i have stated the "pages" project in django.

in pages_project/settings.py file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [ ................... 'pages.apps.PagesConfig', # new ]

TEMPLATES = [ {................. 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],.....}
```

in pages_project/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
 ]
```

in pages/views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Create your views here.

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name='home.html'

class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name='about.html'
```

in pages/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePageView, AboutPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
]
```

i have created three html files in pages/templates/..... home.html, base.html and about.html

home.html code:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%block content%}

<h1>Homepage</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

about.html code:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%block content%}

<h1>About Page</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

base.html code:

```
<header> <a href="home">Home</a>|<a href="about">About</a> </header>

{%block content%} {%endblock%}
```

running python manage.py runserver base.html and about.html is working but when i click on home link it is showing the following:

```
Using the URLconf defined in pages_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
about/ [name='about']
[name='home']
The current path, home, didn't match any of these.
```

but about link is working and base is showing the front face. **this is my first problem.**

after installing heroku and setting up the account. i tried to deposit all the files from git commit. when i write the following command:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
heroku open
```

it shows welcome to heroku page and the second line shows it's documentation page. but it is supposed to show the base.html page. i have used maxthon and mozilla browser for the localhost and used cmd as admin. **this is my second problem**

i stuck on this thing for last couple of days and still don't know how to fix it. i am new to django.

Comment: But this wouldn't have worked in development either. Why didn't you try it there first?

Comment: In local environment it’s working except the home page. I dun know why homepage is not opening through base.html file’s home link.. that was my first problem

Comment: Because the URL isn't "home", it's "/".

Comment: It’s not working if I put ‘/‘ in URLs.py file

Comment: I didn't say to do that. Put it in the link.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are several problems.

First, where did you put your home page template? It should be in pages/templates/**pages**/home.html.

Second, in the pages/urls.py make sure that the home page url is first in the list:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', HomePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
  path('about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
]
```

The order can matter.

Third in the views for pages, re-specify the template name and path:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
template_name='pages/home.html'
```

You can take a loot at the following web pages for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Home_page
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/

base.html should be in project/templates/base.html.
Then in settings make sure that you have the following:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: Not working either. If I put pages/home.html my base.html cannot be opened in local host.

Comment: My bad, also make sure that you have base.html in project/templates. And that you mention the directory of your project-wide templates. I edited my answer. You can take another look.

Comment: thanx for your reply. i have edited pages_project/urls.py as follows: urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('pages.urls')), in this case home page is working but base.html and about.html is not showing . if i add path('about/', include('pages.urls')), then both home.html and about.html is showing but the url becomes http://localhost:8000/home/about/. http://localhost:8000/about/ is not working. i put home.html in new folder pages and the order your talked about but they have no effect because i kept the files in both sides. plz share any new idea

Comment: What exactly do you mean that base.html is not working?. Also, do keep the home.html and about.html in the directory I told you. And make sure that base.html is in the project/templates/ directory.

Comment: If this still does not work, then we can try 1 more time if you want. But the next time, if you can, show me the urls.py file, the directory of pages and project, and the rest of base.html, home.html, and about.html.
More than that...I don't know what to do.

Comment: Also, I meant the urls.py for both pages, and the project-wide one (i.e. the main one).

Comment: pages/urls.py: urlpatterns = [path('', HomePageView.as_view(),name='home'), path('about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),] pages_project/urls.py:urlpatterns = [path('admin/', admin.site.urls),path('', include('pages.urls')),] i put templates/base.html in following directory and that's why base.html page was displayed. templates/pages/base.html won't work. if i put 'home/' in pages_project/urls.py after path() it works only to display the home.html content but base.html and about.html page content are showing 404 error. if you give me your email i can send you the files. thanx man